# Synergy stopped working after a week on Windows7, high CPU usage and no connection

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, synergy

Used synergy 1.3.1 & 1.3.4 since 2007 without a hitch.  Upgraded to Windows 7, and synergy suddenly stopped connecting after a week.  Now any version I try (1.3.1, 1.3.4, 1.3.8, 1.4.5) goes into high CPU usage, no TCP connection makes it through, synergys process uses "Realtime" priority on install.  Windows Firewall is open.  Tried removing ipv6.  Only way to get a TCP connection to go through is to enable "XP SP3 compatibility mode" and "Run as Administrator"... although that's not enough to get keyboard/mouse sharing to work.

Comment: Did you install the correct version (32/64bit)? You don't mention it in your question and it's a pretty important part of troubleshooting...

Comment: @Kyle - I tried both actually.  The OS for my synergy server is 64bit, the first few tries with 1.4.5 and 1.3.8 were with 64bit. Dunno if you know the answer to those, but I was wondering quite a few things when troubleshooting: 1. does the 32bit server work properly on a 64bit os? 2. Is the protocol sensitive to 32/64bit (ex. does the 32bit client work ok with 64bit server)?  3. How much does the protocol change across synergy revision - will I run into problems when troubleshooting my Win7 server+Win7 client if I have my other clients still connected on the same subnet (MacOS + Linux)?

Comment: @Kyle - 4. Does my old *.sgc configuration file from 1.3.4 still work with 1.4.5?  The new interactive configuration interface don't offer the same options as I used to do (IP addresses as aliases, screens split at a percentage value).  5. How good is the support for ipv6 vs ipv4, does it have any impact on the protocol and/or how to connect & identify the server/clients?  -- Cheers, Christian

Comment: Two questions that may help me start troubleshooting:  1. Is this the right place to ask Syngergy questions?  superuser.com is listed on top of the list of support resources on the Synergy website, however I'm not sure if it's the primary resource traffic-wise.  2. Short of single-stepping in the code, what would be the best way to troubleshoot this?  I see nothing of interest in the logs, no indication that client or server can talk to one another, and no explanation why the CPU goes hard to 50% as soon as I start my Synergy server.

Comment: Solved.  Using Synergy 1.4.5, CMSWindowsKeyState::getIDForKey() went into an infinite loop if a Persian keyboard was installed on my system.  Uninstalled that keyboard layout, and synergys.exe now works fine.

Comment: Found workarounds for 2 other problems that randomly prevented me from using Synergy.  #1 Pressing Shift-Alt (switch keyboard) provokes Synergy to get into a key-stuck state (?), VMWare Workstation cannot receive mouse/keyboard events until I press Shift-Alt again. Reproducible 2012-02-27. #2 Farsi keyboard/IME installed on the system makes the Synergy initialization to go into an infinite loop, crashes stack. Reproducible 2012-01-02. #3 Stop Synergy leaves icon in System tray, cannot restart until I remove the dead process' icon by hovering the mouse over it. Reproducible 2012-02.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure scroll lock is not active!  I had a similar problem and ended up here (though the connection was working), deactivating scroll lock solved it!  https://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=217

Comment: Had this same issue happen with 1.4.16. Scrollock was the culprit.